# C# : Delete all files or none from two different directories

Tags: c#, file

I am sorry if it is duplicate. Please point me in right direction. I have 2 directories Dir1 and Dir2. I have one file in Dir1 and 2 files in Dir2.

```
Dir1 
 -Dir1File1.txt

Dir2 
 -Dir2File1.txt
 -Dir2File2.txt
```

Now I need to delete all files in both Dir1 and Dir2. I need to delete all files or none, i.e, if I delete files in Dir1 successfully and when I try to delete files in Dir2 and if something wrong happens then I must rollback my delete in Dir1.

**SOLUTION**

Instead of creating and deleting temp folders this is what I did. I used dictionary to keep track of my the files fullname and data which I want to delete.

```
private static void DeleteAllFilesOrNone()
    {
        string featuresFolder = @"C:\SCD_Sample\Dir1";
        string cfxFolder = @"C:\SCD_Sample\Dir2";

        Dictionary<string, string> featuresFileInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> cfxFileInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        bool rollbackFileDeleteNeeded = false;
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo featuresDir = new DirectoryInfo(featuresFolder);
            foreach (var f in featuresDir.GetFiles())
            {
                string key = f.FullName;
                string xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(key);
                featuresFileInfo.Add(key, xml);
            }

            DirectoryInfo cfxDir = new DirectoryInfo(cfxFolder);
            foreach (var f in cfxDir.GetFiles())
            {
                string key = f.FullName;
                string xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(key);
                cfxFileInfo.Add(key, xml);
            }

            list.Add(featuresFileInfo);
            list.Add(cfxFileInfo);

            //after this any error happens we need to rollback all deleted files
            rollbackFileDeleteNeeded = true;

            //start deleting files
            foreach(Dictionary<string, string> dict in list)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(kvp.Key))
                    {
                        //file exists to delete
                        File.Delete(kvp.Key);
                        //throw new Exception();
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if (rollbackFileDeleteNeeded == true)
            {
                foreach (Dictionary<string, string> dict in list)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(kvp.Key) == false)
                        {
                            //file doesnot exists
                            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Rolled back");
        }            
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any question here... (BTW: *How can I do that* is not a question also)

Comment: @AaronHudon: Note that that other question talks about combining one DB operation and *one file operation* in something like a transaction. The problem of combining *more than one file operation* in a transaction is not touched upon there, and the only and accepted answer is exclusively valid if there is only one file operation, as well.

Comment: I believe this is a valid question.

Comment: I guess you're not using the actual TransactionScope but only getting inspired by it...

Comment: @Ziggler: Try to detail what you have tried so far

Comment: @LuisFilipe isn't `TransactionScope ` only for **database**, not for **filesystem**?

Comment: @LeiYang yes, you are correct. that is why I wrote 'inspired' only :)

Answer (score 7):

A simple way to "simulate" kind of transactional behavior could be to create two temp-directories and MOVE all files from dir1 to tempdir1 and move all files from dir2 to tempdir2.
if both succeed, delete your tempdirs, as you know, there will be no lock on the files.

if any exception occurs during any move operation, just move everything that could be moved so far back to where it was.

Delete both your tempdirs in every case at the end of your operation.

As requested, a bit code here - Sorry I have no Visual Studio at hand, I can't test and code it exactly, I just try to point you in the right direction.

```
string tempdir1 = Environment.GetSpecialFolder.Temp + "\\tempdir1";
string tempdir2 = Environment.GetSpecialFolder.Temp + "\\tempdir2";
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempdir1); 
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempdir2); 

try 
{
    foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(yourdir1, "*.*"))
    {
        File.Move(filename, tempdir1 + Path.GetFilename(filename));
    }
    foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(yourdir2, "*.*"))
    {
        File.Move(filename, tempdir2 + Path.GetFilename(filename));
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Do the same foreach loops again, but from tempdir to yourdir
    // to move everything back
}
finally 
{
    Directory.DeleteDirectory(tempdir1);    
    Directory.DeleteDirectory(tempdir2);
}
```

Comment: @L.B: Why should a question that does not show any code and that does not ask about a specific issue in code be answered with code?

Comment: @grisgram for better coding concatenate directories and filenames use the helpers (.net File and Directory static classes). apart from that good direction

Comment: @LuisFilipe hmmm.. I use the static classes - what does your comment tell me?

Comment: @Grisgram: basically instead of using + "\\tempdir1" to get the path you may use Path.Combine. If you build the path with \ it won't work in Linux

Comment: Well, GetSpecialFolder.Temp is neither correct syntax - this is pseudo code. All others use the statics anyway --- so for pseudo code it is ok imho - but in general I agree, stringconcatenation like this is a bad thing :)

Comment: @Grisgram.. your answer says to create and delete temp folders. That started my thinking but not correct answer since thats not the path we took and in production we are not allowed to create and delete folders and more over we have path that avoids. I appreciate your help but cannot accept it as answer....